# Free text categorization through grep in R

Tags: r

I am an R newbie. I need to categorize free text (customer feedback) into given fixed number of categories. I am trying to run a small code to test the logic.

```
a<-c("a","b","c","d","e") # Category a - if the free text contains any of "a","b","c","d" or "e"
b<-c("f","g","h","i","j") # Category b - if the free text contains any of "f","g","h","i" or "j"
check<-c("a","g","d","j") # Free text to be categorized. "a" should be categorized as a; "g" as b; "d" as a and
                          # "j" as b
count<-length(check)
output<-vector(mode="list",length = count) # Empty categorized list - targeted output is (a,b,a,b)
for (i in 1:count) {
 output[i]<-ifelse(grepl(a,check[i]),"a",ifelse(grepl(b,check[i]),"b","other"))
}
```

I get the following warnings:

```
1. In grepl(a, check[i]) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2. In grepl(a, check[i]) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3. In grepl(b, check[i]) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
4. In grepl(a, check[i]) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
5. In grepl(b, check[i]) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
6. In grepl(a, check[i]) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
7. In grepl(b, check[i]) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Output comes out as (a, other, other, other)

Either grepl is not the right function to use, or maybe there is a way to use vector pattern.
Request your help and guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grepl` complains because the 'pattern' (the first argument) contains multiple patterns instead of just one. One way to solve this would be to collapse your conditions into one regular expression (the `|` denotes 'or'), such as this:

```
a<-c("a","b","c","d","e") # Category a - if the free text contains any of "a","b","c","d" or "e"
b<-c("f","g","h","i","j") # Category b - if the free text contains any of "f","g","h","i" or "j"
check<-c("a","g","d","j") # Free text to be categorized. "a" should be categorized as a; "g" as b; "d" as a and
# "j" as b

# collapse regular expression
a <- paste(a, collapse = "|")
b <- paste(b, collapse = "|")

count<-length(check)
output<-vector(mode="list",length = count) # Empty categorized list - targeted output is (a,b,a,b)
for (i in 1:count) {
  output[i]<-ifelse(grepl(a,check[i]),"a",ifelse(grepl(b,check[i]),"b","other"))
}

output
```

which returns

```
[[1]]
[1] "a"

[[2]]
[1] "b"

[[3]]
[1] "a"

[[4]]
[1] "b"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Bas. It is always so easy in hindsight. :)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer the question you asked, but...  It appears you may be re-inventing the wheel.  I suggest you check out

- The `tm` package (for text mining.)
- *Text Mining with R*, Silge and Robinson, from O'Reilly, esp chapter 2, *Sentiment Analysis with Tidy Data*

Comment: Thanks a lot, David. Had come across it, but being a newbie, was not able to get too much of it. Will be definitely useful, as I go along. Many thanks.